# How to import sql file in stored procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

What I want to do is as follows.

In a stored procedure:

1. Access the DB to retrieve some record of a file name X
2. Check whether a file named X.sql exists
3. source X.sql; (or something similar)

Is that doable? Or do I have to go to UDF?

Thanks.

Comment: this may not be the answer you are expecting, but you can do this easily with bash :)

Comment: I need to access the DB to retrieve the file name.

Comment: @Tony - You can access the DB from bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not everything can be done in SQL.  In particular, it is not possible (without a UDF) to reach outside of MySQL to do file operations (other than `LOAD FILE`).  This is a security limitation.

The "right" way to deal with a requirement is to code it in your application language (PHP / Java / Python / ...).  Some steps would be SQL; some would be file operations.